# Overloading C++ Template functions without copying code

Tags: c++

I wrote the following function:

```
template< class C, typename T, typename U >
void addVarCB(C * _this, const std::string &name, 
    T(C::*getter)(void) const, U(C::*setter)(const T&), const std::string &def);
```

Then I realized that it wont work if setter takes a T as input, so I overloaded the function:

```
template< class C, typename T, typename U >
void addVarCB(C * _this, const std::string &name, 
T(C::*getter)(void) const, U(C::*setter)(T), const std::string &def = "");
```

And now I am realizing that even this will fail if the getter returns

```
const T &
T &
const T *
T *
const T // yeah this is dumb but someone on my team wrote code like this...
```

Am I doomed to copying the same code all over the place?
Hopefully at least solution just for the reference versions?

Note that the function takes a this pointer to an object, a getter and a setter public member functions.
The function will then interface with a GUI allowing the getter and setter to be called back later.

Answer (score 2):

Some template metaprogramming could solve your problem: (The following requires C++11 but the same can be achieved using boost)

```
#include<string>
#include<type_traits>

template<typename T>
struct BaseType {
    typedef typename std::remove_const<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type>::type type;
};

struct MyClass{
    int a;
    std::string s;
    const int & getA() const {return a;}
    void setA(int a) {this->a=a;}
    std::string getS() const {return s;}
};


template< class C, typename Tget, typename Tset, typename U, 
    class = typename std::enable_if<
                std::is_same<
                   typename BaseType<Tget>::type, 
                   typename BaseType<Tset>::type>::value,void>::type >
void addVarCB(C * _this, const std::string &name, 
    Tget(C::*getter)(void) const, U(C::*setter)(Tset), const std::string &def = "") {
}

int main() {
    MyClass c;
    addVarCB(&c,std::string("a"),&MyClass::getA,&MyClass::setA,std::string("a"));
    //addVarCB(&c,std::string("a"),&MyClass::getS,&MyClass::setA,std::string("a")); // Compiler error
}
```

Here we simply let the get and set types (`Tget` and `Tset` respectively) to be deduced independently. We then strip those types of any constness or reference and check if they're the same; if not, we trigger a specialization failure using `enable_if`.

Answer (score 1):

Just make `GetType` and `SetType` independent template parameters, and let the compiler worry about whether they're convertible.

eg. this:

```
template< class C, typename T, typename U >
void addVarCB(C * _this, const std::string &name, 
    T(C::*getter)(void) const, U(C::*setter)(const T&), const std::string &def);
```

requires that `setter`'s argument is a const reference to whatever `getter` returns. However, this:

```
template <typename Class, typename GetResult, typename SetArg, typename SetResult>
void addVarCB(Class *instance, std::string const& name,
              GetResult (Class::*getter)() const,
              SetResult (Class::*setter)(SetArg),
              std::string const &def);
```

allows the `setter` argument and the `getter` return type to be different. Now, assuming you want to pass one to the other, it'll only compile if they're convertible (or you could use C++11 or Boost.TypeTraits `is_convertible` to assert this explicitly).

---

... if that *won't* work, it would probably help if you show what goes inside `addVarCB`, or explain what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Do explain what you mean here, I don't have GetType or SetType anywhere.

Furthermore, "T" cannot be deduced as "const T&" so changing T(C::*getter)(void) to S(C::*getter)(void) does not do anything...

Comment: @aCuria: `T` can very well be deduced as whatever the argument has in a `T (C::*getter)()`, including as a `SomeType const&`.